# model forms were not generated automatically using django model forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm creating Django forms using model forms because u I wanted the forms to be created automatically, but when I created this code the forms do not appear in the index.html page

models.py

```py
from django.db import models


class BaseCase(models.Model):
    base_case_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    version = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    default = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'base_case'
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from SFP.models import *


class BaseCaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta :
        model = BaseCase
        fields='__all__'
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *

def addbc(self, request):
    bcform=BaseCaseForm(request.POST)
    bcform.save()
    basecasename = bcform.cleaned_data['post']
    version = bcform.cleaned_data['post']
    default = bcform.cleaned_data['post']
    bcform = BaseCaseForm()
    return redirect('index.html')
    args = {'bcform':bcform,
            'basecasename': basecasename,
            'version': version,
            'default' :default}

    return render(request, 'index.html', args)
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>S&FP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Forms</h1>
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ bcform }}
       <input type="submit" value="add">
    </body>
</html>
```

and i think that this is important too
urls.py

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^$', views.addbc),
]
```

I was expecting the form fields to be generated automatically but they don't appear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try CreateView which will create forms for your model. Find more about it in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView)

In your case, create a view like this:

views.py

```
class BaseCaseCreate(CreateView):
    model = BaseCase
    template_name = 'index.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app:home')
    fields = ('base_case_name','version','default')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>S&FP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Forms</h1>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
   <input type="submit" value="add">
</body>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: the application doesn't render any html file should use this with the function already defined in views.py

Comment: Create the function inside views and mention that in urls.py . Already did it?

Comment: Hi there, sorry for responding this late, I didn't know which function you are talking about?

Comment: it didn't work. should i define addbc() inside this class?

Comment: CreateView automatically creates a form with fields in the models for you. So, you need not create another function addbc() inside views. I have made an edit. Indentation in views.py